# What operator can I use in Rust to return a specific error if the condition is false?

Tags: rust

I've got the following piece of code:

```
fn foo() -> Result<String, MyError> {
    assert_eq!(vec.len(), 2);
    unimplemented!()
}

pub enum MyError {
    Error1,
    Error2,
    Error3,
}
```

I'd like to return `Err(MyError::Error3)` if `vec.len() != 2` instead of panicking. Is there a way to write it more nicely (by using some operator) other than

```
if vec.len() != 2 { return Err(MyError::Error3); }
```

Comment: You probably mean `MyError::Error3` rather than `MyError:Error3`. The way I see it, there is nothing wrong with an if-statement for that. At best one could write a macro to make it slightly slimmer.

Comment: how do you want rust guess this ?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what variables are present in the code, like where `vec` comes from. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Answer (score 4):

Let's write a macro for that!

```
macro_rules! assert_throw {
    ($cond:expr, $err:expr) => {
        if $cond {
            Err($err)?;
        }
    };
}
```

You can use it like:

```
fn foo(v: &[u32]) -> Result<String, MyError> {
    assert_throw!(v.len() != 3, MyError::Error1);

    Ok("Ok".to_string())
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b8256b9b39e51133dc310fff5c1c59f3))

Comment: In case you are using one of the popular error handling crates, you can use their macro which does more or less the same: [`ensure` in `failure`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/macro.ensure.html) and [`ensure` in `error-chain`](https://docs.rs/error-chain/0.12.0/error_chain/macro.ensure.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to write it more nicely (by using some operator)

Yes, there is. You can use the `?` operator to throw your `Error` to the upper levels.

Alternatively to the macro, you can do this in the if statement as well. You do not need to use `return` keyword. You can basically throw error to the upper levels with `try!` macro or `?` operator.

Please note that using the `try!` macro is deprecated and the `?` operator is favored in modern Rust.

```
fn foo(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Result<String, MyError> {
    if vec.len() == 2 {
        Err(MyError::Error2)?
    }

    unimplemented!()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e5f20e8343d6efbe4bc55d01fbfa3b9)

Comment: this is not really nicer than using `return`. In fact I think it is a bit worse, since you will always `Err` in this case.

Comment: @belst, The OP is asking that are there any option by using `some operator` and there is the `?` operator is giving what the OP wants I think. Besides I do not see any reason why you called it a bit worse in this way? Why did you think that it is worse than using return keyword?

Comment: the `?` operator is only really useful to prevent writing `match foo { Some(a) => a, e => return e; }` in this case you already do the check with the `if` and then still use the `?` operator. It is a bit redundant.

And OP asked if there is a nicer way than the `if` statement in the first place. Which you still have.